Convex cone which is not pointed but which has extreme point 0
I read that if a convex cone $K$ is pointed, in the sense that it contains no straight lines, then $0$ is an extreme point of $K$. Now I wonder if there is some convex cone which is not pointed, but which does have 0 as an extreme point. I cannot think of an example though. Any ideas?

I think your definition of "pointed" is not the usual one. The definition I know is "contains no straight lines through $0$" or, equivalently, $K \cap -K = {0}$.

Consider the upper half plane together with $0$ (but no other points of the $x$ axis).

Great, thanks! :)
